# syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end conversations controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailboxer

I have the mailboxes gem installed and I am configuring it. I have been trying to set it up, however when I visit /conversations I get a SyntaxError `unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end`

I can't seem to see where I went wrong as there are modifications to the original code.

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :mailbox, :conversation

  def index
      @conversations ||= current_user.mailbox.inbox.all
    end

    def reply
      current_user.reply_to_conversation(conversation, *message_params(:body, :subject))
      redirect_to conversation
    end

    def trash_folder     
      @trash ||= current_user.mailbox.trash.all  
       end

    def trash  
      conversation.move_to_trash(current_user)  
      redirect_to :conversations 
      end 

      def untrash  
        conversation.untrash(current_user)  
        redirect_to :back
         end

         def empty_trash   current_user.mailbox.trash.each do |conversation|    conversation.receipts_for(current_user).update_all(:deleted => true)
           end
          redirect_to :conversations
         end

   def create
      recipient_emails = conversation_params(:recipients).split(',')
      recipients = User.where(email: recipient_emails).all

      conversation = current_user.
        send_message(recipients, *conversation_params(:body, :subject)).conversation

      redirect_to conversation
    end

    def reply
      current_user.reply_to_conversation(conversation, *message_params(:body, :subject))
      redirect_to conversation
    end

    def trash
      conversation.move_to_trash(current_user)
      redirect_to :conversations
    end

    def untrash
      conversation.untrash(current_user)
      redirect_to :conversations
    end

    private

    def mailbox
     @mailbox ||= current_user.mailbox
    end

    def conversation
     @conversation ||= mailbox.conversations.find(params[:id])
    end

    def conversation_params(*keys)
     fetch_params(:conversation, *keys)
    end

    def message_params(*keys)
     fetch_params(:message, *keys)
    end

    def fetch_params(key, *subkeys)
     params[key].instance_eval do
       case subkeys.size
       when 0 then self
       when 1 then self[subkeys.first]
       else subkeys.map{|k| self[k] }
       end
     end
    end
```

Routes:

```
  resources :users do |user|

 end

 resources :messages do
   member do
     post :new
   end
 end
 resources :conversations do
   member do
     post :reply
     post :trash
     post :untrash
   end
  collection do
     get :trashbin
     post :empty_trash
  end
end
```

Comment: It'd be good if you lined up your code and properly indented it first. That error is because you have or are missing an extra `end` or a mismatched end. I would assume is in this portion `def empty_trash   current_user.mailbox.trash.each do |conversation|    conversation.receipts_for(current_user).update_all(:deleted => true)
           end
          redirect_to :conversations
         end`. 
Posting the entire stack trace would help much more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing an extra `end` at the end of your controller.